# Rails ActiveRecord Uniqueness Validation Raises Error Still The Record Is Created

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, activerecord

Ruby Version: `3.0.4`

Rails Version: `6.1.7.2`

I have a uniqueness validation check defined in my item model, such that each user can uniquely create only one item.

```
# Modal - item.rb

validates :name, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false, scope: :user_id }
```

```
# Controller - items.rb

def create
  item = @user.items.new(params)

  item.save!

  rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
  .
  .
  .
```

When I receive mutliple parallel requests from the same user with the same item name, then the execption is raised:

```
"exception":"ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid: Name Item names must be unique for a user."
```

But the **record also gets created.**

P.S.:

1. The validation works successfully when the requests are not parallel.
2. When I had received 8 such parallel requests. For the first (original) request the record was created. For the next 7 requests the exception was raised but the 3 duplicate records were also created.

Ideally, the expection should had been raised. But no records should had been created.

Comment: You need to create a constraint in the database to enforce uniqueness -- the validation is not sufficient as you have discovered.

Comment: Yes! I have added the composite unique key constraint in the database. What is bugging me is that the validation raised the expectation but the record still got created.

Comment: If the exception was raised, then the record was not created. Without seeing the code/process you used to arrive at the conclusion that you had 8 parallel requests resulting in 7 exceptions while creating 3 records, it's impossible to explain what actually happened here. If you're still convinced this happened, create a new question showing the test process you went through to create this apparent anomaly.

Answer (score 0):

ActiveModel validations will not handle race conditions caused by processing requests in parallel.

One options is to solve the issue at the database level with a unique index.

```
add_index :items, :user_id, unique: true
```

Another is to use an [advisory lock](https://github.com/ClosureTree/with_advisory_lock) to ensure only one thread is able to execute a block of code at a time

Comment: Sure, thanks. Yes! I have added the composite unique key constraint in the database. What is bugging me is that the validation raised the expectation but the record still got created.